# App crashes when updated from app store

Tags: ios, app-store, updates, segmentation-fault

I released an update to my app with deployment target as 5.0 and Base SDK 6.0.
It crashes with user interaction after taking the update. It crashes only on iOS 5.1 devices not for 6.0 and above. 
Logs shows SIGSEGV error and name _mh_execute_header.
The crash reports suggests some UIKit issues as below

```
UIKit 0x30b3c86d -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] + 160
2   
UIKit 0x30c3b4a7 -[UITextInteractionAssistant setFirstResponderIfNecessary] + 174
3   
UIKit 0x30c3ad71 -[UITextInteractionAssistant oneFingerTap:] + 1608
4   
UIKit 0x30c3a637 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 106
5   
UIKit 0x30bcad65 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:] + 304
6   
UIKit 0x30dfb479 ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke_0541 + 48
7   
UIKit 0x30b46f55 _UIGestureRecognizerApplyBlocksToArray + 176
8   
UIKit 0x30b45aa3 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 898
9   
UIKit 0x30b527e9 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdateGesturesFromSendEvent + 28
```

What could be the possible issue?

Comment: Please provide a full (!!) crash report, and not only some snippet. This doesn't help at all.

Comment: are you sure that you're not using elements that only available on iOS >= 6.0? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS6.html